# delete tag from XML in SQL 8

Tags: mysql, xml

I have this XML table that is called xmlData and is in the saved_games db that keeps saves of users:

```
  <customDataPostLoad>
<game_machine>
    <_string>
        RANDOM STRING DATA
    </_string></game_machine></customDataPostLoad>
```

How can I delete the game_machine all together for all users ? I work with mysql workbench

trying something like this doesnt work:

Update saved_games
SET xmlData = (modify ('delete (/quest_machine)'))

Answer (score 0):

```
update saved_games set xmlData=UpdateXML(xmlData, '/customDataPostLoad/game_machine', '')
```

Or perhaps

```
update saved_games set xmlData=UpdateXML(xmlData, '//game_machine', '')
```

The second parameter to UpdateXML is an xpath to search for; when exactly one match is found, the third parameter replaces it, and the possibly modified xml is returned.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f112d151d425f3bbfe03af025468dcf

Comment: 3 35 13:12:16 Update saved_games
 set xmlData=UpdateXML(xmlData, '//game_machine', ' ') 0 row(s) affected
 Rows matched: 703  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0 0.000 sec

this is what I get :S

I used your second proposal since the game_machine is inside various other tags so searching for it is what I need :)

Comment: Edit your question to show your actual data, or figure out what xpath you need to match

Comment: hmm I see that it deleted the whole xmlData

Comment: 1 14 14:11:55 Update saved_games
 set xmlData=UpdateXML(xmlData, '/quest_machine', '')
 where userUid = '0007b4a2-e9db-4bf1-9962-ebe1032f08cb' 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):
 1525 Incorrect XML value: 'parse error at line 8 pos 19: unknown token unexpected ('>' wanted)'
 Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1 0.047 sec

here is the warning I get, which causes the whole xmlData to be deleted

Comment: ah; probably don't use UpdateXML if it is not actually XML being stored.  but you can do e.g. `update saved_games set xmlData=coalesce(UpdateXML(xmlData, '/quest_machine', ''), xmlData) where userUid = '0007b4a2-e9db-4bf1-9962-ebe1032f08cb'` to keep invalid xml from being changed to null

Comment: ended up paying in codementor someone to fix it and so I can learn how.

this is the result that worked:

UPDATE `tss-sql-test`.saved_games set xmlData= IF (LENGTH(substring_index(xmlData, '<game_machine>', -1)) < LENGTH(xmlData), (REPLACE(xmlData, substring_index(substring_index(xmlData, '<game_machine>', -1), '</game_machine>', 1), '')), xmlData);